# jQuery Supersized: Load images from LI

Tags: jquery, supersized

I am using the jQuery Supersized plugin ( http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/ ).

What I'm trying to achieve is taking an automatically generated list like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><span class="image">/images/image1.jpg</span> <span class="title">My Title</span> <span class="thumb">/images/image-thumb1.jpg</span></li>
    <li><span class="image">/images/image2.jpg</span> <span class="title">My Title</span> <span class="thumb">/images/image-thumb2.jpg</span></li>
    <li><span class="image">/images/image3.jpg</span> <span class="title">My Title</span> <span class="thumb">/images/image-thumb3.jpg</span></li>
</ul>
```

And taking the relevant options and adding it into the slides:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
    $.supersized({
        ...
        slide_links : false,
        slides : [
            {image : '/images/image1.jpg', title : 'My title', thumb : '/images/image-thumb1.jpg'},
            {image : '/images/image2.jpg', title : 'My title', thumb : '/images/image-thumb2.jpg'},
            {image : '/images/image3.jpg', title : 'My title', thumb : '/images/image-thumb3.jpg'}
        ]
    });
});
</script>
```

The system being used does not allow server side code, so I have to do it all in JS.

I have successfully created a simpler way of doing this but it could only be achieved with a trailing comma, which causes pre IE8's to break.

So this was the only solution I could come up with but haven't been able to arrange it so far.

More or less:

Can I take the details in the lists and use them in the slides to generate the background images for supersized?

e.g

This:

```
`<li><span class="image">/images/image.jpg</span> <span class="title">My Title</span> <span class="thumb">/images/image-thumb.jpg</span></li>`
```

To this:

```
{image : '/images/image.jpg', title : 'My title', thumb : '/images/image-thumb.jpg'}
```

With the last having no trailing comma.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build that slides data structure with this jQuery:

```
var slides = [];           
$("ul .image").each(function() {
    var this$ = $(this);
    var obj = {};
    obj.image = this$.text();
    obj.title = this$.nextAll(".title").text();
    obj.thumb = this$.nextAll(".thumb").text();
    slides.push(obj);
});​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/bYs4x/

Comment: What is the call in $.supersized function? I have, slides: slides, but it doesn't work.

Comment: i'm stuck trying to get this to work too... the jsfiddle looks like it gives the correct output but i can't see how to call that array from the supersized script...

Comment: @Dog - you'll need to ask your own question and include the specifics of what you're trying to do (including the code you've tried).  This answer shows how to build a `slides` array from images in particular HTML that is one of the options for the supersized method.  Your situation is likely different and this question is not the place to discuss your particulars.  Please ask your own question and provide your own specifics (HTML, code you've tried, etc...).

Comment: @jfriend - i didn't think it was worth opening a question for this as my problem seems to be identical, and your solution looked perfect... i just couldn't see how i can use the created array with the supersized script... anything i tried gave me js errors... if you think i should i'll open it as a new question...

Comment: @Dog - the slides array that this builds is one of the options for the supersized() method.  It's all explained in the supersized doc and the image array is pretty straightforward as one of those options.  If you don't know how to use the array, then perhaps you need to spend some more time on the doc and the example code.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    myApp = {};
    myApp.doSupersize = function() {

        var slides = new Array();

        $("li").each(function(){
            var obj = {
                image: $(".image", this).html(),
                title: $(".title", this).html(),
                thumb: $(".thumb", this).html()
            };
            slides.push(obj);
        });

        $.supersized({
            slide_links : false,
            slides : slides
        });
    }

    jQuery(function(){
        myApp.doSupersize();
    });

</script>​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: the function inside of jQuery call shouldn't have the $ parameter, should it?

Comment: Nope. I copy pasted it. Good catch :P

Comment: Why do you put the second part inside a ready() handler, but not the first part?

Comment: I dont know, I just wrote the top part and then quickly pasted in their usage code to show how to pass in the slides variable. I assume it would still work that way since slides is a global variable and the ready code should be run after, but its pretty ugly. i guess i can fix it