# jQuery Supersized: how to use array created from LI?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm using the Jquery Supersized plugin and wanted a better way of creating the list of images used.

i found this same question here [jQuery Supersized: Load images from LI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10394456/jquery-supersized-load-images-from-li) but i'm having trouble implementing the solution.

i have a UL with the names of the images like this :

```
<ul id="slide_list">
<li><div class="slide_src">pic1.jpg</div>
<div class="slide_head">head 1</div></li>

<li><div class="slide_src">pic2.jpg</div>
<div class="slide_head">head 2</div></li>

<li><div class="slide_src">pic3.jpg</div>
<div class="slide_head">head 3</div></li>

</ul>
```

i then use the code jfriend00 provided to create an array from this list :

```
var slides = [];           
$("ul .image").each(function() {
    var this$ = $(this);
    var obj = {};
    obj.image = this$.text();
    obj.title = this$.nextAll(".slide_src").text();
    obj.thumb = this$.nextAll(".slide_head").text();
    slides.push(obj);
});​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

my problem is that when i try to use this slides array in the supersized script it gives me an error "'slides' is undefined"

my supersized code looks like this :

```
jQuery(function($){
    $.supersized({

        //Functionality
        slideshow               :   1,      //Slideshow on/off
        autoplay                :   1,      //Slideshow starts playing automatically
        start_slide             :   1,      //Start slide (0 is random)
        random                  :   0,      //Randomize slide order (Ignores start slide)
        slide_interval          :   5000,   //Length between transitions

        //Components
        navigation              :   0,      //Slideshow controls on/off
        thumbnail_navigation    :   0,      //Thumbnail navigation
        slide_counter           :   0,      //Display slide numbers
        slide_captions          :   0,      //Slide caption (Pull from "title" in slides array)
        slides                  : slides
    }); 
});
```

(i've removed some of the supersized option code for brevity).

showing the content of slides array in the console shows me
`[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]`
so i know i'm doing something wrong...

if i use this :
`slidesDisp = JSON.stringify(slides)`

then the array is shown perfectly in the console, 
`[{"image":"pic1.jpg","title":"head 1"},{"image":"pic2.jpg","title":"head 2"},{"image":"pic3.jpg","title":"head 3"}]`

but when i use it in the supersized script nothing happens

`slides: slidesDisp`

any suggestions to what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: How are you getting that in the console when the JS obviously is targeting the class `.image`, and your HTML does'nt match that at all ? Did you post the wrong HTML in the question?

Comment: Where in the code do you define `slides`?

Comment: @adeneo - apologies, copied the wrong class names for my example... i've now corrected in the question... this wasn't causing my problem :)

Comment: @aaron - slides is defined in the first bit of jquery starting with var slides = [];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your HTML does'nt match your javascript, you don't have an `.image` class, and make sure you don't initalize the supersized plugin in a different DOM ready scope :

```
$(function() {

    var slides = [];    

    $("ul .slide_src").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var obj = {};
        obj.image = $this.text();
        obj.title = $this.next(".slide_head").text();
        slides.push(obj);
    });​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

    $.supersized({
        // ...........other options
        slides                  : slides
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you very much, that was my mistake... i had the array created in a $(document).ready and the supersized was in a "jQuery(function($){" further down... i didn't realise variables weren't transferable between differnt jquery functions... the inconsistent class names were when i was writing the question...

Comment: Yes, they are both DOM ready functions, and like any other function they have their own scope, so variables that are not global and created in one scope, won't work in the scope of another DOM ready function etc.